# Why ContractAnnotationAttribute of ReSharper cannot target constructors?

Tags: resharper, static-analysis, design-by-contract

What is the reason why this static analysis attribute is not allowed to be declared on constructors? I would like to annotate that a constructor throws an exception when a null argument is passed.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
internal sealed class ContractAnnotationAttribute : Attribute
{
    //...
}
```

PS: I am asking in a hope that there is a some sort of general principle for this and not just their personal decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an open ticket to add support here which you can vote on, and track: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-401969

However, the only annotation you can apply is that a parameter must be not-null. You can achieve pretty much the same result using the `NotNull` annotation on those parameters.

Comment: I hope they will implement it eventually. Feels incomplete.

Comment: It's not exactly the same result. There's no way with NotNull to explicitly specify how someone passing null anyway would actually be handled. On the other hand, [ContractAnnotation("foo:null=>stop", true)] makes it much more clear that we're going to be seeing an exception.

Comment: Good point. You can try marking the constructor with `[AssertionMethod]`, and then marking each parameter with e.g. `[AssertionCondition(AssertionConditionType.IS_NOT_NULL)]` or `[AssertionCondition(AssertionConditionType.IS_FALSE)]`. These attributes are technically deprecated in favour of `ContractAnnotation`, but are still supported.